# Cache image/gif of Reusable Angular component

Tags: angular, caching

I have created a reusable component say `my-gif-component`. This component has a reference to gif in image tag, something like this,

*my-gif-component.html*

```
 <div>
   <img src="mygif.gif"/>
 </div>
```

Now wherever I use this reusable gif component as `<my-gif-component></my-gif-component>` inside any other component, mygif.gif is fetched from the server the number of times my-gif-component is used in the entire application.

Is there a way to cache the gif/image once and then all other instance of the my-gif-component use that image instead of downloading a new one

Comment: Your browser should already cache it. Take a look at the network tab in the dev tools and you should see that it should be requested once. You don't need to cache it manually. Data Caching is only neccessary if you setup some state managment logic. Files are cache by default form the browser unless you set no-cache mode in meta tag with html.

Comment: When I am running angular application locally, it caches the image. It says `from disk`. But when I am running that application on nginx, each time that component is instantiated, gif is called from network with response 200.

Answer (score 0):

Your server that is serving the gif should send a HTTP header `cahche-control: max-age=yourmaxage` in its response along with the gif
This will make the browser cache the image untill the max-age expires, you should not set max-age to high, as changing the gif will be difficult then.

Depending on whether or not the gif is dynamic you could also consider building the gif right into the application so it is not requested from a server.

Comment: I will see the chache-control option. How do you build a gif in the application?